# TestFlight crash on startup

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, crash-reports, testflight

I'm trying to use TestFlight as crashreporting service. I have followed suggestion reported here

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

I have added TestFlight.dll to my project. Setting up as like

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/TestFlight/sample/TestFlightSample/AppDelegate.cs

published on TestFlight, and installed on device.
When app starts up, it crash immediatelly without a crash report.

If i upload app connecting device via USB app work perfectly.

That is log reported if i connect device to my mac

```
    Incident Identifier: 3F60A316-EEE4-42F5-B4B1-508274D1060F
CrashReporter Key:   3c95c283da9fec03f80d6bd7b4aedec4e78c1f76
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             TestProjectTouch [2508]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/DEA94AB0-147A-495A-92D2-A7428628AB3D/TestProjectTouch.app/TestProjectTouch
Identifier:          com.test.TestProject
Version:             1.0
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-10-30 11:29:43.272 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382081fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826fa4e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x381b9028 abort + 72
3   TestProjectTouch                    0x004aac94 0x7a000 + 4394132
4   TestProjectTouch                    0x004afee2 0x7a000 + 4415202
5   TestProjectTouch                    0x000968fc 0x7a000 + 116988
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3826a720 _sigtramp + 40
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826fa4e pthread_kill + 54
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x381b9028 abort + 72
9   TestProjectTouch                    0x00557d80 0x7a000 + 5102976
10  TestProjectTouch                    0x004ab04c 0x7a000 + 4395084
11  TestProjectTouch                    0x004b8042 0x7a000 + 4448322
12  TestProjectTouch                    0x004aa862 0x7a000 + 4393058
13  TestProjectTouch                    0x004aa01e 0x7a000 + 4390942
14  TestProjectTouch                    0x004a3b34 0x7a000 + 4365108
15  TestProjectTouch                    0x00254b5c 0x7a000 + 1944412
16  TestProjectTouch                    0x0015b540 0x7a000 + 922944
17  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030d600 0x7a000 + 2700800
18  TestProjectTouch                    0x003170d0 0x7a000 + 2740432
19  TestProjectTouch                    0x003172a8 0x7a000 + 2740904
20  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030d6fc 0x7a000 + 2701052
21  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030e780 0x7a000 + 2705280
22  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030d018 0x7a000 + 2699288
23  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030cf7c 0x7a000 + 2699132
24  TestProjectTouch                    0x00308338 0x7a000 + 2679608
25  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030844c 0x7a000 + 2679884
26  TestProjectTouch                    0x0030d2f4 0x7a000 + 2700020
27  TestProjectTouch                    0x00308284 0x7a000 + 2679428
28  TestProjectTouch                    0x003085dc 0x7a000 + 2680284
29  TestProjectTouch                    0x000a39a4 0x7a000 + 170404
30  TestProjectTouch                    0x00234154 0x7a000 + 1810772
31  TestProjectTouch                    0x004b76ea 0x7a000 + 4445930
32  TestProjectTouch                    0x004feffa 0x7a000 + 4739066
33  TestProjectTouch                    0x0047f79c 0x7a000 + 4216732
34  UIKit                           0x30084956 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
35  UIKit                           0x30084714 -[UIViewController view] + 20
36  UIKit                           0x300fc588 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 384
37  UIKit                           0x300faeec -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1196
38  UIKit                           0x300faa32 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
39  UIKit                           0x300fa9ba -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 90
40  UIKit                           0x300fa952 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 38
41  UIKit                           0x300f3454 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 104
42  UIKit                           0x30086394 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 380
43  UIKit                           0x300fa6a4 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 692
44  UIKit                           0x300fa178 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 156
45  UIKit                           0x3008b57c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 460
46  UIKit                           0x30088ae0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 304
47  UIKit                           0x300f3828 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
48  TestProjectTouch                    0x000f1658 0x7a000 + 489048
49  TestProjectTouch                    0x000e4200 0x7a000 + 434688
50  TestProjectTouch                    0x000a6c44 0x7a000 + 183364
51  TestProjectTouch                    0x00234154 0x7a000 + 1810772
52  TestProjectTouch                    0x004b76ea 0x7a000 + 4445930
53  TestProjectTouch                    0x004feffa 0x7a000 + 4739066
54  TestProjectTouch                    0x00477602 0x7a000 + 4183554
55  UIKit                           0x300f0aa8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
56  UIKit                           0x300f04ee -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1386
57  UIKit                           0x300eab3c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 716
58  UIKit                           0x30085a02 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3138
59  UIKit                           0x30084cf8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
60  UIKit                           0x300ea31c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 660
61  GraphicsServices                0x3256a76a _PurpleEventCallback + 606
62  GraphicsServices                0x3256a352 PurpleEventCallback + 30
63  CoreFoundation                  0x2d8c6774 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
64  CoreFoundation                  0x2d8c670e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
65  CoreFoundation                  0x2d8c4eda __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
66  CoreFoundation                  0x2d82f46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
67  CoreFoundation                  0x2d82f24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
68  UIKit                           0x300e95be -[UIApplication _run] + 758
69  UIKit                           0x300e4840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
70  TestProjectTouch                    0x000f7f58 0x7a000 + 515928
71  TestProjectTouch                    0x000b1090 0x7a000 + 225424
72  TestProjectTouch                    0x0009d6b0 0x7a000 + 145072
73  TestProjectTouch                    0x00234154 0x7a000 + 1810772
74  TestProjectTouch                    0x004b76ea 0x7a000 + 4445930
75  TestProjectTouch                    0x004feffa 0x7a000 + 4739066
76  TestProjectTouch                    0x00502d88 0x7a000 + 4754824
77  TestProjectTouch                    0x00502bc8 0x7a000 + 4754376
78  TestProjectTouch                    0x004a1b84 0x7a000 + 4356996
79  TestProjectTouch                    0x005482bc 0x7a000 + 5038780
80  libdyld.dylib                   0x38151ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381f5838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x381440d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3813e61e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381f91c4 kevent + 24
1   libsystem_info.dylib            0x381e6458 _mdns_search + 724
2   libsystem_info.dylib            0x381e5e70 mdns_addrinfo + 284
3   libsystem_info.dylib            0x381e79e0 search_addrinfo + 112
4   libsystem_info.dylib            0x381df788 si_addrinfo + 1052
5   libsystem_info.dylib            0x381df2fa getaddrinfo + 98
6   TestProjectTouch                    0x00090912 0x7a000 + 92434
7   TestProjectTouch                    0x00090856 0x7a000 + 92246
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3813d0c0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x381427d4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 220
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x381429c0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826cdfc _pthread_wqthread + 296
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826ccc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38208c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826ce06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826ccc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38208c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826ce06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3826ccc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x27d85b28
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3a03618c      r6: 0x0056cf0a      r7: 0x27d85b20
    r8: 0x0055ff26    r9: 0x3826a6f9     r10: 0x162a8400     r11: 0x0056ce53
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d85b14      lr: 0x3826fa53      pc: 0x382081fc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

How could i solve it?

Comment: Does it crash on release builds, too? I think I had to put `#if !DEBUG` around the call to setup TestFlight in my projects.

Comment: I have used development provisioning profile on release mode. I haven't tried with release provisioning and certificate. If i set DEBUG what's change? TestFlight setting up is not performed? But it's not that i want...

Comment: The provisioning profile doesn't matter, the build configuration does. Try a `Release|iPhone` build on a device.

Comment: Release|iPhone doesn't upload on my iOS device...but build correctly. If i generate .ipa in Release mode and upload manually on TestFlight it doesn't work same as reported.

Comment: This probably doesn't help you solve your crash problem but if your app is being killed on startup by iOS then TestFlight will not get a chance to send a crash report as your process is just being killed.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Switching to HockeyApp :-P

Answer (score 1):

[Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) just released a fully supported crash reporting solution which fixes that issue (Full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders and CTO).

One of our customers submitted a binding on github, but you can download the official plugin from the Xamarin store here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Comment: Wooow. I need to try!

Comment: Let us know if you have any feedback!